# What should happen when Local notification method calls some other method and our app is executing long function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

How to handle this situation, When I am running a long function process. And I have some Notification that comes in between and I have to execute some task with `didReceiveNotification`.

Note that what i want to do is that i have to stop my function process and have to execute my notification method.

Currently when i pause my mainThread then both the task are getting hanged up. What could be a better way to handle this task.

Comment: What you can do is use a bit of threading concept. If you need more help then feel free to contact me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use RunLoop instead of sleep

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:(NSDate *)];
```